# Transform duplicate rows to columns

Tags: r, reshape

I'm working on a database with hundreds of variables, however, as its origin is JSON, it's making me very difficult to organize it. For example, instead of the file bringing the information in the columns, it creates new lines. See the example.

```
df1 <- data_frame(ID = c(111,111,111,111,111,111,222,222,333),
                  NAME = c('JOHN','JOHN','MARY','MARY','JAMES','JAMES','WILL','WILL','MARK'),
                  ADRESS = c('NY','NY','NY','NY','ROMA','ROMA','LONDON','TOKYO',''),
                  COLOR = c('GREEN','GREEN','RED','RED','YELLOW','YELLOW','BLUE','BLUE','ORANGE'),
                  CAR = c('','','BMW','BMW','TRUCK','TRUCK','FORD','FORD','FERRARI'),
                  COUNTRY = c('USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA','USA'))
```

I would like to organize the file in a way that it is grouped by ID, as in the example below:

```
df2 <- data_frame(ID = c(111,222,333),
                  NAME1 = c('JOHN','WILL','MARK'),
                  NAME2 = c('MARY','',''),
                  NAME3 = c('JAMES','',''),
                  ADRESS1 = c('NY','LONDON',''),
                  ADRESS2 = c('NY','TOKYO',''),
                  ADRESS3 = c('ROMA','',''),
                  COLOR1 = c('GREEN','BLUE','ORANGE'),
                  COLOR2 = c('RED','',''),
                  COLOR3 = c('YELLOW','',''),
                  CAR1 = c('','FORD','FERRARI'),
                  CAR2 = c('BMW','',''),
                  CAR3 = c('TRUCK','',''),
                  COUNTRY = c('USA','USA','USA'))
```

However, note that the `COUNTRY` variable does not need to have numerous columns (COUNTRY1, COUNTRY2, COUNTRY3) as the results are repeated. In my original file, I will find numerous situations like this.
How would I arrange the data evenly in df2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is also with `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
distinct(df1) %>% 
  mutate(rn = rowid(ID)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = NAME:CAR, 
    names_sep = "", values_fill = "") %>%
  select(-COUNTRY, COUNTRY)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 14
     ID NAME1 NAME2  NAME3   ADRESS1  ADRESS2 ADRESS3 COLOR1 COLOR2 COLOR3   CAR1      CAR2   CAR3    COUNTRY
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>    <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>    <chr>     <chr>  <chr>   <chr>  
1   111 JOHN  "MARY" "JAMES" "NY"     "NY"    "ROMA"  GREEN  "RED"  "YELLOW" ""        "BMW"  "TRUCK" USA    
2   222 WILL  "WILL" ""      "LONDON" "TOKYO" ""      BLUE   "BLUE" ""       "FORD"    "FORD" ""      USA    
3   333 MARK  ""     ""      ""       ""      ""      ORANGE ""     ""       "FERRARI" ""     ""      USA
```

Comment: Thanks. As the COUNTRY variable is the same for everyone, I would like it not to change to 3, it would just remain COUNTRY, as in my example in df2

Comment: @BrunoAvila  i think you may need to remove the COUNTRY from the `values_from` (as in the update)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps we can try the following base R code using `reshape`

```
u <- reshape(
  transform(
    unique(df1),
    GRP = ave(seq_along(ID), ID, FUN = seq_along)
  ),
  direction = "wide",
  idvar = "ID",
  timevar = "GRP"
)

u[order(match(gsub("\\.\\d+", "", names(u)), names(df1)))]
```

which gives

```
> u[order(match(gsub("\\.\\d+", "", names(u)), names(df1)))]
   ID NAME.1 NAME.2 NAME.3 ADRESS.1 ADRESS.2 ADRESS.3 COLOR.1 COLOR.2 COLOR.3
1 111   JOHN   MARY  JAMES       NY       NY     ROMA   GREEN     RED  YELLOW
7 222   WILL   WILL   <NA>   LONDON    TOKYO     <NA>    BLUE    BLUE    <NA>
9 333   MARK   <NA>   <NA>              <NA>     <NA>  ORANGE    <NA>    <NA>
    CAR.1 CAR.2 CAR.3 COUNTRY.1 COUNTRY.2 COUNTRY.3
1           BMW TRUCK       USA       USA       USA
7    FORD  FORD  <NA>       USA       USA      <NA>
9 FERRARI  <NA>  <NA>       USA      <NA>      <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need the variables to be immediately after the transformed variable, example: NAME1,NAME2,NAME3, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, Etc...)

Comment: @BrunoAvila See my update

Comment: Thanks. As the COUNTRY variable is the same for everyone, I would like it not to change to 3, it would just remain COUNTRY, as in my example in df2